# Merge iPhone app delegate into another project

Tags: iphone, delegates

I have an open-source iPhone API that I downloaded, and that is a standalone app with its own app delegate and `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method. How do I merge this into my own app, and keep all the methods in the app delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Long Answer**: It is not as easy as a button press, I am afraid.  You will need to inspect the open source app, figure out how it works and where the important hooks are, and self-merge the code.  For example, only 1 applicationDidFinishLaunching will be called so put all code from both in this method.  You probably need to remove duplicate lines and such.

**Short Answer**: you need to understand what each line does and do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Which open-source iPhone API?

A good API may provide an app delegate, but only for example purposes. It probably isn't their intention that you directly merge it into your own app; rather, you could use it as a guideline for how to use the API, by reading the code and seeing how it works. Then, you add the API calls to your own app yourself.